# Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open() failed: No such file or directory

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I'm receiving this warning at the top of my site. can someone provide me a detailed solution on how to fix this.

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/home/content/58/7146558/tmp/sess_g6kr1vkvtfv14ht3hu268issv2, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2 in /home/content/58/7146558/html/upload/include/fgcontactform.php on line 63

Here is the code:

```
    function FGContactForm()
{
    $this->receipients = array();
    $this->errors = array();
    $this->form_random_key = 'HTgsjhartag';
    $this->conditional_field='';
    $this->arr_conditional_receipients=array();
    $this->fileupload_fields=array();

    $this->mailer = new PHPMailer();
    $this->mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';
}

function EnableCaptcha($captcha_handler)
{
    $this->captcha_handler = $captcha_handler;
    session_start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should set session path .in php.ini file:

```
session.save_path = "/path/to/your/folder"
```

Otherwise, you can use:

```
ini_set(session.save_path, '/path/to/your/folder')
```